# Conectar MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, conexão

Tenho um banco MYSQL em uma hospedagem compartilhada UOLHOST, consigo conectar ao banco pelo Server Explorer do Visual Studio normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao tentar conexão através de um aplicação console simples de teste recebo acesso negado:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A diferença clara que observei foi que aparentemente o mysql adiciona junto ao usuário um IP, na conexão via server explorer o usuário fica

> assim:barc@10.129.62.41

e na conexão via console o usuário fica assim:

> 'barc'@'191.17.28.80'

O erro que recebo é este:

> Authentication to host 'barcelona-app.mysql.uhserver.com' for user
>   'barc' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message:
>   Access denied for user 'barc'@'191.17.28.80' (using password: YES

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda senhores!!! Refiz toda a conexão, e agora observei que era o nome do database que eztava incorreto, no uol host a url que geram com server utiliza o nome do banco no início, porém o nome do meu banco contava com underscore e o mesmo foi substituido por traço normal, como copiei o nome do banco da url gerada por eles estava dando este erro!

Comment: Cara, so pra alertar, se essas informações do print forem reais, tira isso do post....

Answer (score 1):

Ola.

1. Primeiro você precisa baixar o [Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html") (ja que você esta usando ADO)
2. Fazer o import `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`
3. Logo pode fazer algo assim

Veja o Codigo abaixo:

```
//define o dataset
mDataSet = new DataSet();

//define string de conexao e cria a conexao
mConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server=localhost;database=Cadastro;uid=root;server=localhost;database=Cadastro;uid=root;pwd=xxxx");

  try{
    //abre a conexao
     mConn.Open();
   }
   catch(System.Exception e)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
   }

   //verificva se a conexão esta aberta
  if (mConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
  {
    //cria um adapter usando a instrução SQL para acessar a tabela Clientes
    mAdapter = new  MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Clientes", mConn);
    //preenche o dataset via adapter
    mAdapter.Fill(mDataSet, "Clientes");
    //atribui a resultado a propriedade DataSource do DataGrid
    mDataGrid.DataSource = mDataSet;
    mDataGrid.DataMember = "Clientes";
}
```

[Veja todo o passo a passo aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2A8tcb_YyY)

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso a seguinte forma para fazer a conexão.

```
class Conexao{

    private const string _strCon = @"server=meuProvedor.com.br;" +
                "user id=Meu_Login;" +
                "password=Minha_Senha;" + 
                "database=Meu_banco;" + 
                "persistsecurityinfo=False";
    private string vsql = "";
    public MySqlConnection objCon = null;

    #region "Métodos de conexão como o banco"

    public bool conectar(){
        objCon = new MySqlConnection(_strCon);
        try{
            objCon.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool desconectar(){
        if (objCon.State != ConnectionState.Closed){
            objCon.Close();
            objCon.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            objCon.Dispose();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Para as consultas:

```
public DataTable ListaGrid(){
    // Esta função lê a tabela Cliente e devolve para um DataGridView.
        vsql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE ORDER BY NOME";
        MySqlCommand objcmd = null;

        if (this.conectar()){
            try{
                objcmd = new MySqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (MySqlException sqlerr){
                throw sqlerr;
            }
            finally{
                this.desconectar();
            }
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

   public string Max(){
    // Esta função busca o maior código de cliente e devolve numa string.
        vsql = "SELECT MAX(CODCLIENTE) FROM CLIENTE";
        MySqlCommand objcmd = null;
        if (this.conectar()){
            try{
                objcmd = new MySqlCommand(vsql, objCon);                    
                return Convert.ToString(objcmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (MySqlException sqlerr){ throw sqlerr; }
            finally{ this.desconectar(); }
        }
        else{ return "0"; }
    }
    public bool Update(ArrayList reg){
    // Esta função faz um update na tabela Cliente e recebe parâmetros num ArrayList
        vsql = "UPDATE CLIENTE SET NOME = @NOME, ENDERECO = @ENDERECO" +
               " WHERE CODCLIENTE = @CODCLIENTE";
        MySqlCommand objcmd = null;

        if (this.conectar()){            
            try{                
                objcmd = new MySqlCommand(vsql, objCon); // Cria comando do MySql
                // Adiciona o arrayList nos parâmetros
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CODCLIENTE", reg[0]));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@NOME", reg[1]));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ENDERECO", reg[2]));                    

                objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Executa a consulta
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException sqlerr){                
                MessageBox.Show(sqlerr, ":: Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
                throw sqlerr;
            }
            finally{                
                this.desconectar();
            }
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

Espero que possa ajudar. Uso esse mesmo método para Sql Server e Access com as devidas alterações.

Answer (score -1):

Saudações !

Amigo, acredito que há varias maneiras de fazer essa conexão.
Aqui vai uma que usei no meu projeto da faculdade do semestre passado.

```
        string Source = "aonde o banco esta";
        string Banco = "qual banco";
        string User = "nome do usuario";
        string Senha = "senha do usuario";

        SqlConnection NewConexao = new SqlConnection("Data Source="+ Source 
            +"; Initial Catalog="+ Banco 
            +"; User Id="+User
            +"; Password="+Senha
            +"; Integrated Security=false");

        NewConexao.Open();
```

Usei esse método para "abrir" minha conexão com o banco sqlServer <-> C#, acredito que possa servir para você com mysql também. 
Espero que ajude.

Comment: Pô, jovem. Você não respondeu a resposta do garoto. Sem contar que a connection string não é assim pra MySQL e que `SqlConnection` não funciona pra MySQL.

Comment: Ele quer fazer a conexão, esse método me ajudou, pode ser que o ajude também. Não te entendo '-'.

Comment: É que sua resposta está errada. Só estou te alertando, daqui a pouco você vai acabar recebendo votos negativos por isso =/

Comment: "Amigo, acredito que há varias maneiras de fazer essa conexão."
"Usei esse método para "abrir" minha conexão com o banco sqlServer <-> C#, acredito que possa servir para você com mysql também. Espero que ajude."
Mas, vlw o alerta.

Comment: Não tinha percebido que você é novo no site. Você pode visitar algumas páginas para entender melhor como funciona o [pt.so]. Como [answer], [tour] e essa pergunta muito interessante do meta [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/18246). Aliás, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]

Comment: Entendo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Nunca vai funcionar @Jonathan Code, pois a namespace do Sql é `System.Data.SqlClient` (diferente de `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`), e não atende as classes do MySql. Se ele já fez o percurso até a conexão, então provavelmente já tem instalado o MySql Connector/Net que fornece o que é necessário. Como ele mesmo já comentou o problema era só o nome do banco.